# Inserting button in image

Tags: image-processing, button

Can I insert a button in an image at specified location? I have tried but it shows Button is not a graphic function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lets get an image:

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
```

`Overlay` is pretty easy to use for location specification. In the case below I used scaled coordinates:

```
Overlay[{img, Button[Style["Image Histogram", Blue, Italic, 34], 
   CreateDialog[ImageHistogram[img]]]}, All, 2, Alignment -> {.7, -.8}]
```

[image]

Here is a simple line to understand better how to place the button in different locations:

```
Overlay[{img, Button[Style["Image Histogram", Blue, Italic, 8], 
     CreateDialog[ImageHistogram[img]]]}, All, 2, Alignment -> #] & /@Tuples[{.7,-.7}, 2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can use an inset:

```
Graphics[{Inset[
   RandomImage[CauchyDistribution[0, .2], {100, 100}, 
    ColorSpace -> "RGB"], Center], 
  Inset[Button["Click Here", Print[10!]], {Center, -0.5}]}, 
 Frame -> True]
```

Answer (score 2):

or maybe you don't want to put it on the image, but somewhere near it 
use this :

```
Column[
{Button["Transform", CreateDialog[ImageHistogram[img]]], Show[
img]]
```

Which works exactly the same but looks a little different.